# using Prompt to add a value to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, web, console

function add (digit){

var figure = digit * 1.5;

console.log("Answer is " + figure);

}

add() = parseInt(prompt(''));

I
need help from someone I want o use the prompt to add a value to the add function parameter
I was expecting the prompt will pop up an input dialogue box in which I will input a value that will be placed in the add() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
function add (digit) {
    let figure = digit * 1.5;
    console.log("Answer is", figure);
}

let value = parseInt(prompt());

add(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code only problem is following part

```
add() = parseInt(prompt(''));
```

instead of above code just use this way

```
add(parseInt(prompt()))
```

```js
function add(digit){

    var figure = digit * 1.5;

    alert("Answer is " + figure);

}

add(parseInt(prompt()))
```